# Can I choose an encounter if I am unable to complete the clues requirement upon passing the test?

Tags: eldritch-horror

The Dimensions Collide mythos card is a rumor card that says "As an encounter, an investigator on space 11 may attempt.... If he passes, he puts an end to their rituals; he may spend Clues equal to half the number of investigators to solve this Rumor"

If I have no clues, can I do this encounter (strategically as a means to avoid any ill effect should I fail the test), and then simply to do nothing if I succeed?

Comment: [Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c7/d6/c7d6cff6-7025-41f9-8538-bb0626feb4f4/eh01_rulebook.pdf) and [Errata](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/3b/54/3b54d99a-0f65-46cb-97e3-7a6f269736e9/eh_errata__faq_2015-01-23.pdf). Can't see anything saying you can't. Not sure I can definitively answer that though. I'm not sure how it could employed strategically though. An example?

Comment: One example is to use the above encounter instead of doing the Sea encounter, as a means to avoid risking an ill effect upon failing a test. Say I am cursed, have 1 health and 1 sanity, and I just want to try to get a reckoning effect to roll away my Cursed condition. I haven't read through all the cards, but I've had a feeling that the Sea encounters more often result in loss or testing to prevent loss (versus positive test results ending in gain), so I used this encounter to simply do nothing that turn.

Comment: Ok - that makes sense now. I can't find a source for it now but I've definitely read previously that if there is a choice and one option would be worse for the players that is the one you choose. I don't feel tactically skipping like that is in the spirit of the game but can't find a specific ruling on it atm.

Comment: It's not so much that choosing to encounter the sea is "worse", it's just riskier, as I could pass the test and gain any number of benefits (this is assuming my thinking that the sea has a lot of bad stuff going on is true--it could be wrong). I'll keep my eye out for that ruling pertaining to veering toward worse outcomes when there is no other deciding factor and post here if I find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because order of operations is important and there is an option in the description, the above situation would be a possible way of avoiding a potentially 'bad' encounter.  Since the card is written in a way to say "First, attempt a  check.  Then, you may spend  clues to remove this rumor.", that means that you can always attempt the check as an encounter, regardless of your clue token total.  The card would need to be written differently if it wanted to use clue tokens as a prerequisite.  Something like "If the investegator has  number of clue tokens, they may attempt to remove this rumor as an encounter."  So, yes, you can use this instead of doing another encounter on the space.